# Is a vnode in TDengine able to split?

Tags: tdengine

After creating many tables in TDengine, there are a lot of vnodes in my TDengine cluster. However, I find one of the vnode is too busy. So I want to split the vnode into two. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

No, TDengine doesn't provide this functionality for user to split the tables in one vnode to 2 or multiple vnodes. The essential of this request is to move some tables out of the busy vnode so that its load can be downgraded to a reasonable level and let another 2 or more vnodes handle the tables moved out. I understand the requirement. However, in near future we will have a feature that TDengine will automatially does some load balancing work once new vnodes are added in the cluster, this can help you. However, the problem of this new feature is that users can't control which tables are moved out to which vnode.

Answer (score 0):

TDengine will automatially does some load balancing work once new vnodes are added in the cluster is not work, we can use "BALANCE VGROUP" ,but this will influence performance, and it will take a long time to finish it when we have a big data cluster